# How to add repository if it doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I currently use the [following command](https://askubuntu.com/a/227788/828892) to add the official ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

But this command add repo without checking if they already exist. So I try to use a bash loop, which is in charge of verifying if they exist or not before adding them

To do it, I am trying to use [this loop](https://askubuntu.com/a/749379/828892):

```
add_ppa() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    grep -h "^deb.*$i" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "Adding ppa:$i"
      sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:$i
    else
      echo "ppa:$i already exists"
    fi
  done
}
```

Maybe it can be used to add repositories like:

```
add_ppa webupd8team/atom xorg-edgers/ppa ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

But not for:

```
add_ppa "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse"
Error: only one repository is needed as an argument
```

the problem is that ubuntu 20.04, when we select manually "restricted" and "multiverse" what it does is add those words to the repository line.

[image]

Example `sources.list`:

before:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports universe main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

after:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports universe main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted multiverse
```

I tried this [other loop](https://askubuntu.com/a/561628/828892), but it doesn't work

```
the_ppa='deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse'

if ! grep -q "^deb .*$the_ppa" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; then
    # commands to add the ppa ...
    sudo add-apt-repository -y "$the_ppa"
fi
```

how do I solve it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/293838/shell-script-to-conditionally-add-apt-repository. I don't really understand why this post was closed.

Comment: @harrymc it was likely closed because there is no indication of what is wrong with these commands *as is*. Simply copy and pasting them will run all the commands so why do you need to repeatedly loop over them again and again? Alternatively why does simply running them *not* do what is desired? Part of the puzzle is missing in this question, along with the obligatory "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: @Mokubai: My understanding of the poster's question, however laconic, is that it's answered in my link. Many posters don't really know what to try...